# How to pass two-dimensional array to function

Tags: c++, arrays

I wrote a little programm and I can't pass two-dimensional array `words[10][max_row_size]` to function `notify`. Please help me if you can. 
 a part of code attached.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <fstream> 
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;
#define max_row_size 100
int notify(char words[max_row_size]);

int main(void) {
    ifstream dictionary("dictionary.txt");
    //ditrionary looks like 
    //hello-world
    //universe-infinity
    //filename-clock
    string s;
    int i=0;
    char words[10][max_row_size];
    while(!dictionary.eof()){
        dictionary>>s;
        strcpy(words[i++],s.c_str());
    }
        notify(words[max_row_size]);

    return 0;
}

int notify(char words[max_row_size]){
        cout<<words[1];
    return 0;
}
```

[It is a full code of my programm, may be it can help you](https://github.com/remasik/notify_words)

It is an errors
`/home/rem/projects/github/notify_words/notify_words.cpp: В функции «int notify(int, char*)»:`
`/home/rem/projects/github/notify_words/notify_words.cpp:65:113: предупреждение: format «%s» expects argument of type «char*», but argument 3 has type «int» [-Wformat]`

Comment: In general, it's always good to post the error that your code produces. That way it's easier to help.

Comment: Here is a comprehensive answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8767247/1837457

Comment: compilation result - OK

Comment: error in execute `bash: string 1: 32447 error of segmentation                   (ready dump core) '/home/rem/projects/development/cpp_test/1'`

Comment: Adding a link to my post on full code.

Comment: This problem is different from the original problem. Now the problem is that you do `words[random_notify]` which returns a char and not a pointer to a char. Try `&words[random_notify]`

Comment: `notify(i, words);` 
`int notify(int i, char (*words)[100]);`

it's work

Answer (score 0):

You pass words on its own: `char** words` is the argument in the function: i.e.

```
int notify(char** words){...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want notify to print just one word, so you need to change notify to

```
int notify(char* word){
    cout<<word;
    return 0;
}
```

But also the way you're calling notify will probably not produce the results you're after.

```
notify(words[max_row_size]);
```

Will try to get you the 100th word out of 10. Which will probably cause a crash.

You probably want to place notify last in your while loop and call it like this

```
notify(words[i]);
```

Also, if you have more than 10 words in your dictionary, you're in trouble. You might want to try a [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) instead of an array (because vectors can grow dynamically).

Comment: yes, crash
`cannot convert «char*» to «char**» for argument «1» to «int notify(char**)»`

Comment: two-dimentional array is not a pointer to pointer so this aint gonna work

Comment: No, but when passed to a function you can treat them as if they were. Of course you would have to change the call to notify(words). I had a closer look at the code and tried to suggest some code that does what I think the OP is actually trying to achieve.

Comment: I want output random element of words every 10 minutes. I call notify every 10 minutes from main. Please see https://github.com/remasik/notify_words/blob/master/notify_words.cpp

Firstly it finds amount of rows in my dictionary in main() to `int strings`, then it creates array `words[strings][max_row_size]`, max_row_size = 100. Then content of dictionary writes to `array words` and then I try to pass array `words` to notify function and output random string.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way for 2 dimensional array (obviously, you can typedef your array):

```
int notify(std::array<std::array<char, max_row_size>, 10>& words){
    std::cout << words[1];
    return 0;
}
```

Easiest for an array of strings:

```
int notify(std::array<std::array<std::string>, 10>& words){
    std::cout << words[1];
    return 0;
}
```

This way prevents that the array is decayed to a pointer in the function, so the size is still known.

Answer (score 0):

```
notify(char words[][max_row_size])
```

to pass the whole array down

then use `notify(words);` to call the method

But really you should be using standard containers instead of arrays